# Equivalence of change of metric sign convention and exchange of space and time components in 4-vectors?

Tags: special-relativity, metric-tensor, vectors

I´ve recently come across a property of, which could be either banal or rather (even physically) interesting, and on which I´m by no means equipped to have an opinion about.

Considering two arbitrary four-vectors $C$ and $D$ the inner product is (with metric sign convention $(+ - - -)$)
$$C · D ≡ C^0 D^0 − \vec{C} · \vec{D}$$
and choosing the 1-axis parallel to $C$ or $D$ it becomes
$$C · D = C^0 D^0 − C^1 D^1.$$
Now exchanging the time component $C^0$,$D^0$ and space component $C^1$,$D^1$, i.e. $C^0 ↔ C^1$, $D^0 ↔ D^1$, it becomes
$C · D → C^1 D^1 − C^0 D^0 = − C^0D^0 + C^1D^1 = - (C^0 D^0 − C^1
D^1) = − C · D.$

The four-vector inner product changes sign, and the exchange of components, or exchange of space and time coordinates, seems to be equivalent to a change in the sign convention of the metric from $(+ - - -)$ to $(- + + +)$ (or vice versa).

I´m unsure if this is merely a algebraic, or conventional, matter which is completely irrelevant to the physics or if this has any implications, (physical) interpretation or meaning?

Comment: You may want to use [MathJax](https://physics.stackexchange.com/help/notation) to make the equations better readable.

Comment: Its merely convention. The physics is unchanged whether you choose to use the mostly positive/negative metric convention.

Comment: @ThomasFritsch Sorry, first time on here. Thanks a lot for the tip!

Comment: This is also known as west-coast and east-coast metric.